# Carrierwave custom headers on local files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I'd like to send all files from a certain uploader with custom headers (specifically, the content-disposition header). My files are NOT stored on Fog / S3, they're stored locally.

So I was wondering, is it possible to attach certain headers on a file?

Answer (score 3):

On the file itself no. It depends how do you server those files. If the files are served directly by your webserver you need to adjust the configuration files. If the files are served by a controller from your app you can modify the headers on the action that is dealing with it.

Here are some hints

1. for nginx http://jeremywalworth.com/index.php?q=node/41
2. for apache https://serverfault.com/questions/101948/how-to-send-content-disposition-headers-in-apache-for-files
3. for lighty http://azgtech.wordpress.com/2011/01/26/force-download-pdf-using-lighttpd/
4. if you try to serve the files using a rails controller you should take a look at ActionController::DataStreaming#send_data documentation.